# Clone object in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

I have 3 classes which are given below:

**Company.kt class:**

```
data class Company(var comCode:String= "",var comName:String=""):Cloneable{
fun copy() : Company {
  //uses the fields name and property defined in the constructor
  return Company(comCode,comName)
}

override fun clone(){
    super.clone()
}
}
```

**Emp.kt class:**

```
 data class Emp(var name:String,var empCode:String,var nameArray:MutableList<Company>){

fun copy() : Emp {
  //uses the fields name and property defined in the constructor
  return Emp(name,empCode,nameArray)
}

//or if you need a copy with a changed field
fun copy(changeArray :MutableList<Company>) : Emp {
  return Emp(name,empCode ,changeArray)
}

}
```

**DeepCopy.kt class:**

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){

var company1 = Company("com1","company1")
var company2 = Company("com2","company2")
var company3 = Company("com3","company3")
var company4 = Company("com4","company4")
var company5 = Company("com5","company5")

var list:MutableList<Company> =mutableListOf();
    list.add(company1)
    list.add(company2)
    list.add(company3)
    list.add(company4)
    list.add(company5)
val emp = Emp("krishan","oms360",list)
println("old emp>>>>>>> "+emp.nameArray[1].comCode)
val listtemp = emp.nameArray
listtemp[1].comCode= "COM10";
//var cloneEmp = emp.copy(listtemp)//.apply { this.nameArray[1].comCode= "COM10"; }
//cloneEmp.nameArray[1].comCode= "COM10";
//cloneEmp.empCode = "oms400"
println("new emp>>>>>>> "+emp.nameArray[1].comCode)

}
```

When I get `nameArray` from emp object in new object like this

```
val listtemp = emp.nameArray
listtemp[1].comCode= "COM10";
```

and change the value of first position of list, after that print emp object, that object print changes().

**result:**

```
old emp>>>>>>> com2
new emp>>>>>>> COM10
```

Comment: Emp object should not change. please suggest

Comment: You're editing the array of `emp` object, why would it not change? You never make a copy of the array.

Comment: @pawal sir. I want to copy of the array, how is it possible?

Comment: please give some update code hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the outcommented part of the code is where you try making a deep copy and it ended up changing the `emp` object as well, otherwise your question makes no sense, as the code clearly changes `emp` object. In case I assumed right, try changing your `copy()` function to:

```
data class Company(var comCode: String= "",var comName: String= "") {
    fun deepCopy(comCode: String = this.comCode, comName: String = this.comName) 
        = Company(comCode, comName)
}
```

--

```
data class Emp(var name: String,var empCode: String,var nameArray: MutableList<Company>){

    fun deepCopy(
        name: String = this.name, 
        empCode: String = this.empCode, 
        nameArray: MutableList<Company> = this.nameArray.map {it.deepCopy()}) = Emp(name, empCode, nameArray)
}
```

then, if you want to make a copy, just do:

```
val newEmp = emp.deepCopy()
// val newEmp = emp.deepCopy(empCode = newEmpCode) // in case you want a different code for your newEmp. Similarly for other fields.
```

Comment: error is coming in Emp class ----- conflicting overload: public final copy Emp(var name: String,var empCode: String,var nameArray: MutableList<Company>) Emp defined in Emp .

Comment: Actually, kotlin data classes have their own copy() function implemented, have you tried the default copy function? If it still does not give you deep copies, then use the code I wrote, just rename copy(...) to something else, deepCopy(...) for example, and use it instead of the default copy() funtion.

Answer (score 0):

Generic clone function:

```
fun <T : Any> clone (obj: T): T {
  if (!obj::class.isData) {
    println(obj)
    throw Error("clone is only supported for data classes")
  }

  val copy = obj::class.memberFunctions.first { it.name == "copy" }
  val instanceParam = copy.instanceParameter!!
  return copy.callBy(mapOf(
    instanceParam to obj
  )) as T
}
```